# iOS - Firebase Messaging: What is kGCMMessageIDKey?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement chat with Google Firebase. I'm following the tutorials but I cannot continue because an undeclared variable is being used and I cannot find its origin anywhere. The variable is called `kGCMMessageIDKey`.

It is being used first in here as:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {

    NSLog(@"Message ID: %@", userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]);
  }
```

In the sample project, `kGCMMessageIDKey` is declared in the AppDelegate as

`NSString *const kGCMMessageIDKey = @"gcm.message_id";`.

I have a feeling that this is a constant I should obtain from the Firebase dashboard but I cannot find any corresponding ID there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value should be the unique id for the message and should match the message_id parameter for the message that you'd see while interacting with Firebase Cloud Messaging APIs. You can also use that value to reference the message when using the FCM API/services from the device.

Yes, it seems that you either need to paste that constant declaration into your code, or replace it with `@"gcm.message_id"`. The value does not seem significant and this code snippet is mainly for debugging.

I would encourage you to set a breakpoint in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and examine the contents of `userInfo` to familiarize yourself with the message payload and the various attributes available to you from both FCM and iOS. When the breakpoint is hit, type the following into the debugger:

```
(lldb) po userInfo
```